# How can I exclude a user role from being changed when logging in?

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles

I am trying to modify a code snippet I have been using for some time on my WordPress site. Previously, when a user with the default 'Subscriber' role logged in, the role would be changed to 'Directory User'. I had excluded the 'Administrator' role from being changed. I want to keep this behavior but I have added a new user role, 'Directory Contributor' that I don't want to be changed either. I have come up with the following code, but the 'Directory Contributor' role is being changed to 'Directory User'. How can I modify my code so that this does not occur?

```
    function uiwc_change_role()
{
    // get WP_user object
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $role = $user->roles;
    
    // if the this is a registered user and this user is not an admin or directory contributor
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !user_can($user, 'administrator', 'directory_contributor') && !in_array('directory_user', $role)) {

        //set the new role to directory user
        $user->set_role('directory_user');
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'uiwc_change_role');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `array_intersect` since $role is an array. `user_can` checks for capabilities, and not user roles, so it's probably best to leave it out of the picture here.

It also seems more sensible to hook to `init` unless you have some other reason not to.

```
function uiwc_change_role() {
    // get WP_user object.
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $role = $user->roles;
    // if the user is a registered user and this user is not an admin or directory contributor.
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && ! array_intersect( array( 'administrator', 'directory_contributor' ), $role ) ) {
        // set the new role to directory user.
        $user->set_role( 'directory_user' );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'uiwc_change_role' );
```

Comment: That seems to have done the job. Thank you!